# VSCode Requires Carriage Return for Python Print

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm running the following statement in VSCode by opening up the test.ps1 file and hitting F5. The problem is that it won't print "hi mom" in the VSCode Terminal window until I focus in the Terminal window and hit carriage return. it will hang there forever.  I don't have this problem in the normal PowerShell ISE, it prints immediately. Any ideas?

**Test.ps1**

```
python d:\RepoStats\Python\Test.py
```

**Test.py**

```
print("hi mom!")
```

Comment: Probably this is a result of buffering... What happens if you `print("hi mom!", flush=True)`?

Comment: Good idea,unfortunately it didn't work.